# How to specify colclass when I use write.csv in r?

Tags: r

I have an ID column in my data frame like this:
"00012","00123","12345","00002"

But when I use write.csv in R, the output CSV automatically dismiss the 0s in the front, like this:
"12","123","12345,"2"

How can I fix this? I want the ID column print as the original one.

Comment: When I run `write.csv(data.frame(x=c("00012","00123","12345","00002")), "test.csv")` and then look at the file created in a text editor, I see that all the zeros were preserved. How are you looking at your file? Are you trying to open it in Excel or something? Excel is the one that's likely stripping the leading zeros, not R.

Comment: yes, actually my final goal is to open it with Excel. (or CSV is ok, I can transfer it to Excel). I tried to paste " ' " in front of my ID numbers, but in excel it prints as "'00012", "00123"..., with " ' " in the front.

Comment: Excel mangles data in CSV format. If your only use of this CSV is to import data into Excel, you should use a package that outputs an excel file. Otherwise you basically have to create an invalid CSV to trick excel into treating the column as a character. R is doing the best it can. Excel is the real enemy here.

Comment: Please provide data in a reproducible format that you have and the code that you have used to write the csv.

Comment: You can also open Excel then go to Data --> Get Data --> From File --> Text/CSV and try to define the exact column types manually.

Answer (score 2):

The claim in the question is not so.  write.csv does preserve the leading zeros.  (You can omit the last two arguments shown of write.csv depending on what you want.)

```
DF <- data.frame(ID = c("00012", "00123", "12345", "00002"))
write.csv(DF, stdout(), quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
## ID
## 00012
## 00123
## 12345
## 00002
```

While the above answers the question as stated I noticed in comments that the problem turned out to be incorrect reading of the csv output in Excel as opposed to R not creating the correct csv output.  For that

1. see: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keeping-leading-zeros-and-large-numbers-1bf7b935-36e1-4985-842f-5dfa51f85fe7
2. or write to an excel file directly

   ```
    library(writexl)
    write_xlsx(DF, "myfile.xlsx")
   ```

Comment: Yes, it true when I see the dataframe in R, it preserves the zeros. But when I open it with excel or CSV, it omits the zeros. However, now I find one solution in excel. I can set the number format and fill the zeros.

Comment: The question already stated that the data frame contains the leading zeros so that is not the point.  The point is that write.csv preserves them.

Comment: Yes. Now I find that excel is the problem here. The question is misclassified here, my fault. Thanks!